# How can I extract the intercepts between two planes and visualize them?

Tags: plotting

Below is the data for my first plane:

```
data = Flatten[Z = 0.01; Table[{X, Y, 4*Z*Y/X}, {X, 2, 20, 0.1}, {Y, 2, 10, 0.1}], 1];
```

The second plane is  `z = 0.01`

```
ref = Table[Z = 0.01, {x, 2, 20, 0.1}, {y, 2, 10, 0.1}];
```

Now I have plotted both the planes.

```
ListPlot3D[{data, ref}, PlotRange -> {{2, 20}, {2, 10}, {0, 0.2}}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As we can see that roughly the X-intercept range is `{8, 20}` while the Y-intercept range is `{2, 5}`

How can I extract these ranges and visualise them in the plot?

[Edit 1: `Delta = z = 0.01`]
[Edit 2: Updated the expression for `data`]

Comment: You did not provide `Delta`. Anyway, you could interpolate `data` and do something like `NSolve[interpolation[x,y]==0.01,{x,y}]`

Comment: @mattiav27 Sorry for that. I have updated the question by adding the value of ``Delta``

Comment: But your picture is `Z=0.01` instead of `Z = 0.001`.

Comment: @cvgmt Actually, I drew two lines (``Z=0.01`` and ``Z=0.001``). Therefore, by mistake, I pasted the wrong line. I have updated it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. It seems you simply need to solve `0.01=4*0.01*Y/X` as a function of `X` or `Y`. If this is the case `Solve[1/100==4*1/100*Y/X,X]` will give the answer.

Comment: @mattiav27 I need the coordinates of the endpoints of the intercepting line. It should be approx {8, 2.1, 0.01} and {20, 5, 0.01}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {{2, 20}, {2, 10}, {0, 0.2}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0.01}}, MeshShading -> {Directive[Orange, Opacity[.1]], None}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- The intersection points.

```
data = Flatten[Z = 0.01;
   Table[{X, Y, 4*Z*Y/X}, {X, 2, 20, 0.1}, {Y, 2, 10, 0.1}], 1];
plot = ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {{2, 20}, {2, 10}, {0, 0.2}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0.01}}, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
(*pts=DiscretizeGraphics[plot]//MeshCoordinates*)
pts = Cases[Normal[plot], {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y, z}, 
   Infinity];
Graphics3D[{Point[pts], AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, 
  Point[{pts[[1]], pts[[-1]]}]}, Boxed -> False]
pts[[1]]
pts[[-1]]
```

> `{8., 2., 0.01}`
> `{20., 5., 0.01}`

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Now, how can I extract and display the intercepting points?

Comment: @Majis  See the updated. The `pts`  are all the points in line.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I want the end coordinates like ``{8,20,0.01}`` and ``{2,5,0.01}``. I got it by just solving the equations.

Comment: @Majis The beginning point and the  ending point.  `pts[[1]]` and `pts[[-1]]`

Answer (score 2):

You may use "Mesh" to draw a line with constant z==0.001:

```
data = Flatten[Z = 0.001; 
   Table[{X, Y, 4*Z*Y/X}, {X, 2, 20, 0.1}, {Y, 2, 10, 0.1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[data, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> {{0.001}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Now, how can I extract and display the intercepting points?